# On PCIe 1.0, does a 64 bits graphic card could be compatible with 32 bits OS (Windows 7 32bits)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, 64-bit, 32-bit, pci-express

On PCIe 1.0, does 64 bits graphic card could be compatible with 32 bits OS (Windows 7 32 bits) ?

Is there any restriction?

**Edit:**

> Few peoples told in comments that bitness should not be an issue. If I
>   understand well, it is only a question of is there any supported
>   drivers for the specific OS (here Win 7 32 bits) ???

**Edit2:**
I finally bought a 64bits graphic card with PCIe 1.0 interface and it work nicely on my Windows 7 32 bits... Thanks to all !!!

Comment: If a card specifies 64-bit, then usually there's a reason. Perhaps the driver is only 64-bit.

Comment: the "bitness" of the card is only the bandwidth that it communicates with the computer, it doesn't relate anything to the computer's architecture. And the connection between the two is by "special I/O ports" that has no relation to the "bitness" of the computer

Comment: I've never heard of PCIe devices referred to as either 32bit or 64bit. I've only heard them referred to as x1, x4, x16, etc. Are you sure you're not referring to PCI-X 1.0?

Comment: as @LưuVĩnhPhúc mentions, the bitness usually refers to the memory bandwidth pipe. There's no such restriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit width of the bus (PCI, PCI-X, AGP, PCIe, etc) has nothing to do with the processor word size. It is simply the number of bits the communication channel can carry at a time.

The southbridge (now part of the Intel PCH or AMD chipset) handles the communication between the CPU and expansion cards (including video cards), so the bit width of the bus does not create any restrictions on the processor architecture.

Ultimately, whether your system can use the cards attached to your computer's expansion slots comes down to whether appropriate drivers are available.

Answer (score 2):

There are three options here:

1. The card only has 64 bit drivers (unlikely, though 32bit systems are finally dying and eventually no new software will be written for them. This might take a few more years though).
2. It is not PCI-e. Joeqwerty's comment about PCI or PCI-X might be on target. PCI comes in 32 bit and in 64 bit flavours. PCI-e comes in lanes.
3. The most likely situation: The speed of a graphics card depends mainly on two factors:

   - The Graphics chip (the GPU)
   - The speed in which the GPU communicates with the on-board memory.

   The latter is influenced by the memory speed and by the width of the path to the memory. This width is often **64**, 128, 192, 256, 384 or 512 bit.
   All of which is unimportant to the OS. The OS just needs the right (32 or 64 bit) driver to match its own setup.