# Does 64 bit graphic card work in a 32 bit processor

Tags: graphics-card, 64-bit

I don't know much about hardware. My PC has window 8 32-bit installed. And I want to buy a graphic card 2gb ddr3 but I'm confused that it says it has architecture of 64-bit in it. Does it install on 32-bit or should i go for it?

Zotac Nvidia gt 610 2GB ddr3 
-opengl 4.2
-64 bit
-1066 MhZ

Comment: Yes; It will work.  If you want an actual answer please provide specifics about the graphic card in question.

Comment: Different wording, but essentially the same as http://superuser.com/questions/767204/on-pcie-1-0-does-a-64-bits-graphic-card-could-be-compatible-with-32-bits-os-wi

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 64-bit (or even 128-bit) in the GPU specification is the [GPU memory bus width](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/explain-to-me-how-memory-width-128-192-256-bit-etc-is-related-to-memory-amount.170588/). It's not a requirement for CPU register (it's not stating a requirement of a 64-bit CPU)